# Import CSV using mongoimport with types of the column

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, csv, mongoimport

Am using mongoimport with defined field type --columnsHaveTypes. When i import the file got an error

> Failed: type coercion failure in document #1 for column 'time', could not parse token '2020-09-08T09:41:19.693+0300' to type date>

i used the below command

> mongoimport --db main --collection data --type csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields="time.date(2006-01-02),duration.int32(),entry.string()" --file="path\to\test.csv"

Answer (score 0):

`2020-09-08T09:41:19.693+0300` is not standard representation of date/time so mongoimport cannot parse it.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6 defines local offset as

> time-numoffset  = ("+" / "-") time-hour ":" time-minute

Your string lacks a colon. `2020-09-08T09:41:19.693+03:00` will be parsed correctly.